# How to run Thunderbird in a portable way, without using C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\...?

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird, user-profiles

With Mozilla Thunderbird, the default storage for data is in `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\...`. Even if we want to move a `Profile` folder to another path, we have to fill this information inside `C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\...\profiles.ini`,
as explained in [Moving a profile (official documentation)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data#w_moving-a-profile):

> In the profiles.ini file, locate the entry for the profile you've just moved. Change the Path= line to the new location.

**How to totally bypass this `C:\Users\User1\AppData` folder and use Thunderbird as a real portable software?**

PS: I don't want to use the ["PortableApps"](https://portableapps.com/) version. Even if this project seems trustworthy, I'm not sure the "repackaging" script is fully open-source, and anyway, I don't want to add another layer if we can do it without this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have two versions of Mozilla Thunderbird on same computer (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1402379/can-i-have-two-versions-of-mozilla-thunderbird-on-same-computer-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As I searched for this since years, now that I found the answer, I share it with the "Q&A-style" StackExchange feature.)

- First install it (with the official installer) to your desired path, e.g. `D:\Portable\ThunderBird\app`
- Create another empty folder `D:\Portable\ThunderBird\profile`
- Create a shortcut like this:

  ```
   D:\Portable\ThunderBird\app\thunderbird.exe -profile "D:\Portable\ThunderBird\profile"
  ```

  [image]
- Run this shortcut!

Notes:

- Documentation about [Command line arguments - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29)
- More about [Running from a USB drive](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Running_from_a_USB_drive_%28Thunderbird%29)
- Some files will still be saved to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\...`: `Crash Reports`, `Pending Pings`, but you can forget about that. **What's important (the email data) will be in `D:\Portable\ThunderBird\profile`.**

Comment: It's a cool workaround, but FWIW, I've used Thunderbird Portable for years, and I've never had any issues with it, not even when they at Mozilla switched from XUL extensions to web extensions, and there was this hodge-podge of mixed extensions that came, and went, and came back, then were out the window again. I'd be more interested in a real way to place the *cache* in RAM (specifically in a RAM disk I've already created), the way you can with Firefox. I've edited my T-Bird profile that way, but it's not 100% fool-proof.

Comment: @Didier Thanks for your comment. If I find something about cache in RAM I'll ping you!

Comment: PS @Didier: I didn't find if "PortableApps" bundles are really 100% open-source; their engine probably is, but I mean is the repackaging script for which `input=thunderbird-official-installer.exe` (or source code + building script) `output=portableapp-thunderbird-package.exe` available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this article [Profile on USB drive](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Running_from_a_USB_drive_%28Thunderbird%29). If your computers of choice can be guaranteed to have the same version of Thunderbird on then that is preferable to actually installing it on your USB drive.

Write performance is very important. This means using USB 3 as anything lower will cause random stalls while changes are flushed back to the drive. Also, set the drive for maximum performance (Device Manager -> Disk Drives -> each USB drive -> Properties -> Policies). This requires correct ejection of the USB drive, though, as opposed to simply pulling it out.